# How to get the difference between time on same table but on different lines

Tags: c#, sql, database

I would like to know how to get the difference between time if the data is in the same table but on two separate lines. For example, below I have a screenshot of the data, every employee have two records, the first clock point and the last clock point. I want the difference between those times and save it into a new table. How do I do that?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RefinedData](
[ClockNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Department] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ClockPoint] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Date] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Time] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Layout of Data:
[image]

So in this case I want the time difference of the user Gerard saved in a new table but only one record per user.

Comment: Are  you sure you always have two entries for user Checkin/CheckOut

Comment: Please provide test data to be inserted

Comment: What about clock #93? Entered twice without leaving? Your table is missing vital information, that currently could only be established by text parsing.

Comment: Also I would strongly recommend to normalize table, and add correct primary key

Comment: How do the employees of your company (which is easy to find) feel about you publishing non-anonymous information about them?

Comment: Do u always have 2 rows in table ?

Comment: When your question is lacking in terms of information required to solve the problem correctly, you need to provide that additional information, otherwise you end up with a bunch of answers that contain assumptions about the data that don't stack up. At the time of writing this comment, every single one of the answers below have some sort of assumption about information that you didn't provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is apparent from your sample data , you have 2 rows of data per user.
`row_number` will work for you. Subtracting rn2-rn1 will return required output

```
with cte as
(select  [ClockNo] ,
        [FirstName] ,
        [LastName] ,
        [Department] ,
        [ClockPoint] ,
        [Date] ,
        time,
        ROW_NUMBER() over partition by clockno,firstname order by date,time) rn
        from mytable 
        ) 

        select  c.[ClockNo] ,
        c.[FirstName] ,
        c.[LastName] ,
        c.[Department] ,
        c.[ClockPoint] ,
        c.[Date] ,
        c1.time -c.time
        from cte c inner join (select * from  cte where rn= 2) c1 
        on c.rn = c1.rn-1 and c.firstname = c.firstname and c.clockno = c1.cloclno 
         where c.rn = 1
```

Comment: The entries and exits are not guaranteed to be contiguous, as shown by entry #93 above. This will fail.

Comment: This answer is correct. I would add the "Date" column inside the order by in the window function, just to make sure not to calculate time difference between different days.

Comment: Clock point should be out on entry 93, could be a typo, OP should confirm

Comment: @EzequielLópez Cheers. I have added date column to ensure rows are unique

Comment: What if the employee enters before midnight and leaves after midnight? Is it safe to assume that this will never happen?

Comment: As i have mentioned this query works only for 2 rows and on same day, I guess OP has poorly formatted schema/table

Comment: Another problem would be, if employee leaves more than once and returns more than once

Comment: Don't worry about if an employee leaves more than once. That has been caters for. In this table each employee will only have 2 entries. @spender This is just dummy data but I wanted to make it look as realistic as possible. Also don't take the ClockPoint column serious as for now I just want to subtract whatever 2 values are available.

Comment: @JohnaneUmslana If the table have only 2 entries, this query definitely  works, it would begood to select records into a temp table by date

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
var differences = 
    refinedData.GroupBy(d => d.ClockNo)
               .Select( g => g.OrderBy(d => d.Time))
               .Select( g => new {
                   ClockNo = g.ClockNo,
                   Difference = g.Last() - g.First() });
```

Comment: No mention of LINQ here.

Comment: @spender But it does mention c#. I find it hard to imagine what else the c# tag can entail apart from linq in the present context.

Comment: @InBetween I see tag "sql" for sure

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
select Firstname,cast(max(Time)-min(Time) as time) as 'time difference'
into #temptable
from RefinedData 
where FirstName like 'Gerard'
and Date like '20180301'
group by Firstname
```

Comment: When they enter and exit more than once, what will happen?

Comment: now it will subtract the min time from max time for the particular date

Comment: So now they entered and exited twice on the same day... what now?

Comment: ...or they entered before midnight and left after midnight? This is a dairy, so that's not unlikely.

Comment: so he will subtract earliest entry from the last exit for the same day

Answer (score 0):

Here something you can start with:

```
select *, datediff(hour, LAG([Datetime]) over (partition by FirstName, LastName order by [Datetime]), [Datetime]) [Difference_in_hours]
from (
select FirstName,
       LastName,
       ClockPoint,
       --get correctly formatted date column
       cast(stuff(STUFF([DATE], len([DATE]) - 3, 0, '-'), len([DATE]), 0, '-') + ' ' + stuff(STUFF([time], len([time]) - 3, 0, ':'), len([time]), 0, ':') as datetime) [Datetime]
from [RefinedData]
) a where
ClockPoint like '% out %' or
ClockPoint like '% in %' or
ClockPoint like '% out' or
ClockPoint like '% in' or
ClockPoint like 'out %' or
ClockPoint like 'in %'
```

Comment: Once again, look at entry #93 and have a think about the sanity of arbitrarily choosing contiguous entries.

Comment: @spender I don't get it. What do yo umean?

Comment: You're using LAG to pick out the entry from the previous row. There's no guarantee that this pairing of times is going to give you both an entry and an exit (i.e. a clocked-in time span). ClockNo 93 above demonstrates this problem.

Comment: @spender The question is little bit unclear on those cases... But you're right and added `where` clause to get closer to OP's requierements.