# How to determine total hours from multiple entries

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I would like to get the total hours for each employee. The details of the data is as follows:

- There are two entries per user per day, 1st entry is the login time
  and the second entry is the log off time.
- Some users might not have entries for everyday.

I want the total hours worked per user for the week.

[image]

Above is a screenshot of the data.
I want to get the total hours worked per user in a new table.
How to I achieve that?

Comment: Select all the data out. Sort it by Date then Time. Then process the data in batches of 2 (using https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#batch). Each batch is a start and stop combination. Subtract start from stop. Total for each batch.

Comment: You should really include the code that you have tried.

Comment: Do not store date and time as integers. 
Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Also, Do not post sample data as a screenshot. Post it as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) and [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Your question should also contain the desired results (As formatted text!) and your current attempt.

Comment: Are the `Date` and `Time` columns really stored as Integers or does it look that because it's how you've presented them?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze They are intergers

Comment: This post is just a continuation of your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108217/how-to-get-the-difference-between-time-on-same-table-but-on-different-lines) - you need the same calculation **and** you need to sum the results of that calculation. And all the same caveats apply. Try writing some code rather than asking others to do it for you.

Comment: if you provide DDL, as already mentioned, then you'll get more chance of getting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you must first do is convert the Integer `DATE` and `TIME` data to formats you can `CONVERT` to `DATETIME` or `TIME` datatypes so you can then execute DATE functions, like `DATEDIFF`, against

Integer `DATE` to `DATETIME` datatype

```
DECLARE @date INT = 20180320
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(@Date AS CHAR(8)), 101)
```

> 2018-03-20 00:00:00.000

```
DECLARE @time INT = 215319
SELECT  RIGHT(
            CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, (@Time / 1000000) % 100,
                    DATEADD(MINUTE, (@Time / 10000) % 100,
                        DATEADD(SECOND, (@Time / 100) % 100, CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME(2)) ) ) )
                AS NVARCHAR(16))
            , 8)
```

> 21:53.00

Then combine the lot, using a derived table, LEAD

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ClockNo INT, FirstName NVARCHAR(50), LastName NVARCHAR(50), [Date] INT, [Time] INT)

INSERT INTO @t(
      ClockNo
    , FirstName
    , LastName
    , [Date]
    , [Time]
)
SELECT 111, 'J', 'Doe', 20180320, 80620     UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'J', 'Doe', 20180320, 170124    UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'J', 'Doe', 20180322, 75436     UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 'J', 'Doe', 20180322, 120854    UNION ALL
SELECT 132, 'S', 'Doe', 20180319, 134630    UNION ALL
SELECT 132, 'S', 'Doe', 20180319, 215319    UNION ALL
SELECT 132, 'S', 'Doe', 20180320, 134630    UNION ALL
SELECT 132, 'S', 'Doe', 20180320, 215319

SELECT X.ClockNo
     , X.FirstName
     , X.LastName
     , TotalHours = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, X.LogOn , X.LogOff)) * 1000, 0), 114)
FROM(
        SELECT 
              T.ClockNo
            , T.FirstName
            , T.LastName
            , T.[Date]
            , LogOn     = CAST(
                                        CAST(T.[Date] AS CHAR(8)) + ' ' + RIGHT(
                                                                            CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, (T.[Time] / 1000000) % 100,
                                                                                    DATEADD(MINUTE, (T.[Time] / 10000) % 100,
                                                                                        DATEADD(SECOND, (T.[Time] / 100) % 100, CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME(2)) ) ) )
                                                                                AS NVARCHAR(16))
                                                                            , 8)
                                        AS DATETIME)

            , LogOff = CAST(LEAD(
                                CAST(T.[Date] AS CHAR(8)) + ' ' + RIGHT(
                                                                        CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, (T.[Time] / 1000000) % 100,
                                                                            DATEADD(MINUTE, (T.[Time] / 10000) % 100,
                                                                                DATEADD(SECOND, (T.[Time] / 100) % 100, CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME(2)) ) ) )
                                                                            AS NVARCHAR(16))
                                                                        , 8)
                                )
                                OVER
                                    (   PARTITION BY T.ClockNo, T.[Date] 
                                        ORDER BY T.[Date], T.[Time]
                                    )
                        AS DATETIME )
        FROM 
            @t T
) X
GROUP BY
      X.ClockNo
    , X.FirstName
    , X.LastName
```

Returns

```
ClockNo FirstName   LastName    TotalHours

111     J           Doe         13:09:00:000

132     S           Doe         16:14:00:000
```

**Caveat - solution only works if the LogOn and LogOff occur on the same day**

Answer (score 2):

Because you're only pulling two values, you can group by the user id (which I'm assuming is ClockNo) and the date and then use the MIN and MAX functions to pull the start and end time for each day. Once you have the interval, you can then sum up the results by user.

```
SELECT
    ClockNo
,   MIN( FirstName ) AS FirstName
,   MIN( LastName ) AS LastName
,   SUM( [Hours] ) AS TotalHours
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ClockNo
        ,   MIN( FirstName ) AS FirstName
        ,   MIN( LastName ) AS LastName
        ,   [Date]
        -- Not sure what the time format is, you'll need to adjust this
        ,   COALESCE( MAX( [Time] ) - MIN( [Time] ), 0 ) AS [Hours] 
        FROM
            ClockTable
        GROUP BY
            ClockNo, [Date]
    ) AS HoursPerDay
GROUP BY
    ClockNo
```